# Writing an instance(s) of a class in a file in json or xml

Tags: java, xml, json, scala

I have the list of instances of a class which kind of complicated: it have many val's including nested classes those also have many val's. I want to write in a file in either `json` or `xml` format.

I found a simple example which seems to do what I want (in Java, though, but it really doesn't matter):

```
#Main.java
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            Employee employee = new Employee("0001", "Robert", "Newyork City", "IT");

            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("my-data.txt");
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);

            oos.writeObject(employee);

            oos.flush();
            oos.close();
            System.out.println("Employee Object written to file employee.dat");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

#Employee.java
import java.io.Serializable;


public class Employee implements Serializable {
    private String empId;
    private String Name;
    private String Address;
    private String Dept;

    public Employee(String empId, String name, String address, String dept) {
        this.empId = empId;
        this.Name = name;
        this.Address = address;
        this.Dept = dept;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "[Employee: " + empId + ", " + ", " + Name + ", " + Address + ", " + Dept + "]";
    }
}
```

And what I had as an output was a **binary** data written in a file. Moreover, `toString()` methods enumerates all fields manually, which is unacceptable for my real class.

So how do I do that? I'd really  appreciate if you give even a small example of it, instead of saying "there is a library called X, use it". I've already failed using all these libraries in my previous question about serialization. I'm not sure yet if what I need is serialization, because I need it to be stored in not binary, but in xml or json format.

Comment: Add an example of how the result text file should look like

Comment: @om-nom-nom as i understood he doesn't want to serialize it, but to write in human readable format in file, but not in binary

Comment: @AlexIv xml and json are relatively human readable, that questions I've linked above are not about *binary* serialization, but about serializing to json/xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example using Jackson:

```
final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
final String s = mapper.writeValueAsString(yourEmployee);
```

`s` contains the JSON as a string.

You can then read back that value and convert back to a POJO as well. [Javadoc for `ObjectMapper`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html).

As @veritas mentions in the comment, you can extend Jackson, customize {de,}serialization etc -- heck, you can even have it brew coffee. But defaults are pretty good already, so you may not even need to delve into its depths.

Comment: Jackson api can be extended to achieve any mapping between java objects and json. also see the online tutorial http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you'll use a library that knows how to serialize a POJO object into XML or JSon.
Take a look at [JAXB](http://thomassundberg.wordpress.com/2010/01/19/how-to-convert-a-pojo-to-xml-with-jaxb/) or [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/). [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) is also an option.